# WPF/c# Access from Page.xaml to Dataset

Tags: c#, database, wpf

So far I have mainly worked with Access VBA.

Now I am in the process of creating a database application with WPF and C#. As a base I have an AccessDB.
The connection between WPF/C# and Access is done via a DataSet.
When I create an XAML window in WPF and drag the fields from the database into the window, the following action is automatically created in XAML.cs

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {}
```

With this code, behind "Window_Loaded", the access to the database works.

Now I wanted to implement this process with a page window.
However, it does not work there.

I have already searched for an example, but did not find one.

My question, where can I find an example or a tutorial where such a thing is well explained?

Answer (score 0):

Search about entity framework. It's can help you very much to bind data.

You can create a dataGrid to bind data inside then and in every row create a button to select a row. Now you can do what ever you want like Edit and Delete

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this solves my problem.
The Entity Framework does not know Access, I only get access to SQL Server or SQL Server database file.

I have looked at some examples with Entity Framework, they all work with Windows.xaml too. There it automatically creates "private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)", but that doesn't work with a Page.xaml.

Somehow I can't find an example that shows me how to read data from a DataSet.xsd.